# Facing "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io" in command prompt

Tags: java

While trying to compile the Java code facing this problem. Let me know what is missing here.

> javac -cp ".;C:\path for the folder\WEB-INF\lib\commons-io-2.0.1.jar"

GroupJavaScriptFiles.java

java GroupJavaScriptFiles

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you need to use the same `-cp` option when you run the class as when you compiled it.

```
java -cp ".;C:\path for the folder\WEB-INF\lib\commons-io-2.0.1.jar" \
        GroupJavaScriptFiles
```